# iOS - UITableViewCell being clipped

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView with a tiled background image

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]];
```

With this image pattern I have noticed that on every 3rd table cell the pattern does not match and a line is clearly seen on the background image. At exactly the same position the bottom of my UITableViewCell is being clipped so I am losing the bottom of my cell. I am assuming that both these problems are linked.
I was wondering if someone could explain what is happening here and perhaps offer a suggestion to fix my table cell from being clipped.

The image on the right is the **clipped** cell and the image on the left is the normal cell

[image: Normal Cell]
[image: Clipped Table View Cell]

Comment: Does your tableview have any headers or sections?  Also have you tried setting the table view's cell separator to none?  Not sure if this has anything to do with it, but might be worth looking into.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Nope, I dont have any headers or sections and I dont have any table separators either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted this. I was changing the UITableViewCell frame origin value to create a gap between table cells that was causing this problem.

```
self.contentView.frame.origin.y = 20;
```

Instead of this I just adjusted the bounds to create the gap between cell rows.

```
CGRect bounds = self.contentView.bounds;
bounds.size.height = bounds.size.height -20;
self.contentView.bounds = bounds;
```

Hope tis helps someone in the future